# MVC Facebook Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am working on one application which require Facebook Login.

I went through various blog and it is clear how to implement facebook or any other third party login. However just bit confused regarding login persistence/ Or process when user comes to website second time.
What i need is

- User come on website and can choose wether he want to register or want to login with facebook.
- Once he log in with facebbook i need some additional information from him and i will store that information along with his userid in the database.
- If he log off, and comes again to website he will again provide his facebook login details.
- once he do that i will get his facebook user id and with the help of that i can create a session easily.
- BUT not in case he is already logged in from facebook in the browser and if he try to browse my website, then i have to redirect him to authorized page directly. In that case i have to implement a solution which will take care of this issue. While searching i found one blog which might be the way how to implement it. [Facebook Login Filter](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Facebook-Connect-Action-Filter-for-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)

But is there any other way i can achive it?

Comment: If you want to “recognize” a visiting user that is logged in to Facebook again server-side, then you must send their browser to the login dialog URL – they will be redirected back to your site immediately if they already logged in to your app using FB before and you don’t ask for any additional permissions. But doing so automatically would be bad for users that don’t even use Facebook – so you should not do it automatically, but only when they request it via a link/button.

Comment: If you want to do this automatically/without a redirect, then you have to use the JS SDK to determine their login status client-side. Then of course you can not determine it on initial page load, it will require a second request to your server for it to know their status.